# Tmux cannot find window

Tags: tmux

I am using tmux after logging into our university server. I have multiple screens  (created with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>), some for editing different files. Some for running programs. I go through the tasks with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>p</kbd>, but sometimes this takes long to find the right one.

Is there a shortcut to a screen running some specific program. Or is there some other way to manage the screens (sometimes ten or more)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get a list of "screens" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>.
This shows the main program running without any options, so that help a bit but not much.
You should  name your screens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> after you make them, that will make that list much more useful.

This is what I get after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>, you can select the entry with <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>, or by clicking with the mouse.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

See the `list-windows` option in the man page:

> list-windows [-a] [-F format] [-t target-session]
>                    (alias: lsw)
>              If -a is given, list all windows on the server.  Otherwise, list windows in the current session or in target-session.  For
>              the meaning of the -F flag, see the FORMATS section.

From within tmux, open a command line with <kbd>:</kbd> and then issue the command:`list-windows` to see a list:

```
0: TTYtter  (1 panes) [142x60] [layout b07d,142x60,0,0,0] @0
1: NZOSA  (1 panes) [142x60] [layout b07e,142x60,0,0,1] @1
2: SSH  (1 panes) [142x60] [layout b07f,142x60,0,0,2] @2
3: IRC  (1 panes) [142x60] [layout b080,142x60,0,0,3] @3
4: Shell- (1 panes) [142x60] [layout b081,142x60,0,0,4] @4
5: bash* (1 panes) [142x60] [layout b082,142x60,0,0,5] @5 (active)
```

If you use this command frequesntly, bind it to a key to make it more convenient to run:

```
bind-key C-w list-windows
```

Comment: I tried typing ":" but that just goes to the program that is running in the screen (vi command prompt eg)

Comment: Sorry I see first Ctrl-B